# Plutus local haddock server not working

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, documentation

The problem: when I run `build-and-serve-docs` from within a nix-shell and inside the `plutus-app` repository, the server runs up and on the CLI i get the message `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8002 (http://0.0.0.0:8002/) ...`. But, when I try to navigate to this address, I get a `Not possible to access` error message. As if the server was not even running, because I don't even get an HTTP error response.

My environment: WSL2.

Comment: Maybe try http://127.0.0.1:8002/ ? Both that and 0.0.0.0 work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the shell tells you this:

> Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8002 (http://0.0.0.0:8002/)

Just go to this location:
http://localhost:8002/haddock/

The given 0.0.0.0:8002 does not work, however these do work:

http://localhost:8002/haddock/

http://localhost:8002/

(Im using WSL too)

Comment: This did the trick, but I had to do a `cabal build` first as well. Forgot about it.

Comment: One more comment. 127.0.0.1 also works (of course).